# Singleton-like pattern for cases when hiding constructor is not possible?

Tags: java, android, singleton

I know *Singleton-pattern*.

I'd need to achieve two-way communication between two class instances, but instantiation is not done by me (but by some 3rd party library).

This 3rd party library has also a requirement that a public default constructor has to be available in this form:

```
public MyClassA(Context ctx);
```

This 3rd party library will initialize two of my classses `MyClassA` and `MyClassB`.

What's the most efficient/recommended technique to communicate (call each other's functions) between them?

So, 3rd party library instantiates `MyClassA` with its constructor shown above. It also instantiates `MyClassB` (which has the very same signature as `MyClassA`).

Then upon some events by this 3rd party (which calls `MyClassA`'s implemented method named `onEvent0`) I need to call `MyClassB`'s instance's `doSomeAction` function:

```
3rdpartylib::notify -> myclassa::onEvent0() -> myclassb::doSomeAction
```

I know I could store an instance when the 3rd party instantiates my classes, but is it the recommended way, if we take into account the Android platform which has some nice `Handler`, and `ServiceConnection` paradigms?

Comment: "Then upon some events by this 3rd party (which calls MyClassA's implemented method named onEvent0) I need to call MyClassB's instance's doSomeAction function" -- why? Why cannot `MyClassB` hold some other object, which your `MyClassA` object could then call `doSomeAction()`? For example, `MyClassB` (and perhaps `MyClassA`) could be thin wrappers around other objects that do the real work, where those other objects are obtained via a dependency inversion framework (Dagger/Hilt, Koin in Kotlin, etc.). You would have greater flexibility in connecting those other objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Observer Design Pattern to solve this. As your problem clearly states you need to invoke some function in myClassA by 3rdpartylib's notification.

Create a subject class, your 3rdpartylib will call func `notifyObservers`.

```
public class ThirdPartyLibSubject {
    private List<ThirdPartyLibObserver> observers = new ArrayList<>();

    public void register(ThirdPartyLibObserver observer){
        observers.add(observer);
    }

    public void unregister(ThirdPartyLibObserver observer){
        observers.remove(observer);
    }

    public void notifyObservers(){
        observers.forEach(ThirdPartyLibObserver::update);
    }
}
```

Now create the observers for your subject, this way you can keep the Singleton property of your class `MyClassA`

```
public interface ThirdPartyLibObserver {
    void update();
}

public class ObserverClassA implements ThirdPartyLibObserver{
    @Override
    public void update() {
        MyClassA.getInstance().onEvent0();
    }
}
```